# Do I need to re-index my Volume?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, spotlight

I recently installed a brand new HD in my macbook pro.

I did this by cloning the original drive.

Everything (almost) is working fine, but I did give the Volume a different name, it used to be Macintosh HD and now it's Hybrid HD (not sure if this matters).

Ever since using the new drive (two weeks now) spolight doesn't seem to be working properly. It just doesn't find things that are there. Although something's indexed because it does return results (usually mail.app stuff).

Anyone know the reason for this, or how I can fix it?

cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open terminal and type:

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

- You will be asked for your password, provide it, as this command
  requires administrator privileges to run.
- After confirming your Spotlight index will be re-built and your files
  should appear in the search. ( Depending on the size of your HDD it
  can take a while )

To turn Spotlight on/off use:

```
sudo mdutil -i on /
sudo mdutil -i off /
```

To fine tune your Spotlight settings open System Preferences > Spotlight

[image: Spotlight Preferences]

Exclude certain folders from getting indexed:

[image: Exlude from Spotlight]

Comment: +1 thanks ioi. I'll try that. From my question, is there anything that would suggest why this happened in the first place?

Comment: There could be several reasons, depending on how you cloned your original hard drive. Your new Hard Drive also has a unique UID associated with it, which is actually the name your Mac uses to identify it; so renaming it shouldn't have any effect, because the computer always knows it as something like: 02F64515-4F23-400B-8608-B8D44F12A34D ...